# How does the electric field inside a conductor become zero?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

When a conductor is placed in an external electric field, I know that the free electrons arrange themselves in such a way that the field inside the conductor due to these charges cancel the external field.

If the external field was uniform, then the field due to these induced charges would have to be uniform too.

How is an arrangement of electrons ( and positive charges)  possible so that it produces an uniform field at all points inside the conductor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electric field inside a conductor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/85974/)

Comment: @semoi: I disagree this is a duplicate. The question referred to deals with a hypothetical "depletion" of particles due to an excessively large field. This question is about how electrons can possibly arrange in such a way to create a zero electric field inside the conductor, i.e., what is the surface charge density as a function of position that causes this.

Comment: It is not clear what the issue of this question is about. I mean, it is possible for the charges to be arranged in a way that creates uniform fields -- plates capacitor is an example. Why would the charges fail to arrange a uniform field?

Comment: Electric field in a capacitor is uniform because we assume the distance between the plates is extremely lesser than the plate dimensions; this assumption need not be true in the case of a conductor